# Vulkan Run Time libraries are installed in my computer. Should I delete them?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

After hearing about Vulkan in the past (It's like OpenGl - but better), it made me quite happy. But not so much after Nvidia stated that the Geforce 500 series would not receive driver support for Vulkan API.

Despite them claiming that my GPU (Geforce 550 Ti) would not be supported, somehow the Vulkan Run Time libraries get installed onto my system. At first I thought I somehow installed it myself, but then after doing the annual Windows re-installation, I've caught a glimpse of the same program installed on my PC.

The Vulkan demos do not work on me ol' PC so I'm wondering if there is any point in having this program on my PC at all.

Comment: "It's like OpenGl - but better" - Technically it is simply the next version OpenGL.  It sounds like the Nvidia drivers are installing the Vulkan runtime.  It is normal for AMD/Nvidia to install the OpenGL/Vulkan runtime by the way.

Comment: I'm guessing that this will be always installed during GPU driver updates. It just makes me wonder why do they would install this if the hardware doesn't support it. They don't let me install software like ShadowPlay and etc. as my GPU does't support it but they still install Vulkan.

Comment: Your GPU supports OpenGL, Vulkan is the next version of OpenGL, I highly suspect the installer is also installing the legacy OpenGL files also. As for the reason, they might install Vulkan/OpenGL even if there isn't system support, contact Nvidia for the reason.

Comment: As far as I know Vulkan and Opengl will continue on in parallel. Vulkan is not a replacement for Opengl, it's just a more lowlevel performant way of doing things. Apple has no plans to support Vulkan at this point, so opengl continues to be the only cross platform interface.